# upgrading to XCode 8 broke my ability to build on my iOS 6 device?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently upgraded to XCode 8, and found that I can no longer build on my iPhone5 with iOS 6...  Fortunately I kept around XCode 7, but apparently since I installed XCode 8, I somehow lost some linking for a dispatch queue symbol?  When I try to run my app with XCode 7 on iOS 6, I now get an immediate crash:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/0FE3B5A4-00AA-46F3-80A7-8EA45C64BEAE/myapp.app/myapp
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: side question, why in the world would this get down voted?

Comment: Probably because in October 2016, you are worrying about iOS 6. No serious developer is worrying about iOS 6. Any designs made for iOS 6 will be unusable for iOS7 to iOS10. iOS8 usage is below 4% now.

Comment: @gnasher729, I am a game developer, not using a "design".  Making sure apps are backwards compatible should be viewed as a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation for `dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class`. Note when it was added - iOS 8. You have to guard against the use of that function when run under iOS 7 or 6.

As documented in the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i), you can do this:

```
if (dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class != NULL) {
    // use dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class as needed
} else {
    // The function doesn't exist for this device, do something else
}
```